# jquery strategy for updating multiple parts of a UI with the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web application using jquery 3.2.1

On page load a PHP script is rendering the markup for the UI. This contains a list of categories and then tables of associated data.

As an example:

```
<!-- Category list -->
<ol>
    <li>Foo (3)</li>
    <li>Bar (19)</li>
    <li>Baz (2)</li>
</ol>
```

And then various tables that are associated with these categories:

```
<p>Foo: 3 records</p>
<table id="fooTable">...</table>

<p>Bar: 19 records</p>
<table id="barTable">...</table>

<p>Baz: 2 records</p>
<table id="bazTable">...</table>
```

The markup above is generated on page load, via PHP. No JavaScript has been used at this point.

The tables are then updated via ajax calls - using jquery. I can obtain the total number of records that are returned in my ajax response.

But this got me thinking about how best to update parts of the UI where those numbers are referenced via jquery.

My "solution" to this was to wrap the appropriate numbers in a known class. Then in the ajax response, target this class and update the appropriate data. For example if we consider the "Foo" category, a known class (`.foo-count`) has been wrapped around the figures I want to update:

```
<!-- Category list -->
<ol>
    <li>Foo (<span class="foo-count">3</span>)
    <!-- ... -->
</ol>

<p>Foo: <span class="foo-count">3</span> records
<table id="fooTable">...</table>
```

So in my ajax `.done()` callback I can do things like this:

```
$('.foo-count').empty(); // Clear out the existing number (3 in this case)
var foo_count = ... // Variable to hold response data giving updated count.
$('.foo-count').html(foo_count);
```

This seems quite convoluted especially with multiple categories.

Is there a better solution for this type of issue?

Comment: Can you provide a running example of your "ui"? This will make it easier to find a solution or giving  good advices.

Comment: Given jQuery's non-reactive nature compared to more modern frameworks, your approach seems quite reasonable

Comment: Using jQuery, this is probably the best solution.  Although, I think the `.empty()` is unnecessary.  And you can use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty is there a particular framework that makes this kind of task easy and do you have a link to an example of where that type of task is being done? It's possible for us to use other frameworks in this project, but I don't  want a solution that's overkill just to do this type of task. In other words if the solution I've presented in jquery is less overhead than adding in another framework, then what I have now would be the preferred solution.

Comment: I prefer Vue.js it's way simpler than Angular (and React?) but still may be overkill for just this